# How to redistribute wxHaskell apps?

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I am using ghc 7.6.3. I installed wxHaskell from here: https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell

It worked, the sample programs compile and the run successfully.

The only problem now is that I want to distribute a wxHaskell application on mac OS X. I tried using macosx-app and cabal-macosx (https://github.com/michaelt/cabal-macosx) to make an "app" file. It runs fine on my machine, but it fails to run on another computer. I get the following error:

```
Dyld Error Message: Library not loaded: /Users/user/.cabal/lib/wxc-0.90.1.0/ghc-7.6.3/libwxc.dylib.
```

I am using OS X 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion), but I would be also interested in compiling apps on Windows and redistribute them too.

What would be the best way to redistribute wxHaskell apps?

Setup.hs

```
-- Example Setup.hs for the wxHello app.

import Distribution.MacOSX
import Distribution.Simple

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMainWithHooks $ simpleUserHooks {
         postBuild = appBundleBuildHook guiApps -- no-op if not MacOS X
       }

guiApps :: [MacApp]
guiApps = [MacApp "WxHello"
                  (Just "resources/WxHello.icns")
                  Nothing -- Build a default Info.plist for the icon.
                  [] -- No other resources.
                  [] -- No other binaries.
                  ChaseWithDefaults -- Try changing to ChaseWithDefaults
          ]
```

wxHello.cabal:

```
Name:                   wxHello
Version:                0.1.0
Stability:              Alpha
Synopsis:               wxWidgets `Hello World' example for cabal-macosx
Description:
    Example showing how to use cabal-macosx to build an application
    bundle for a simple `Hello World' program using the wxWidgets GUI
    toolkit.
Category:               Data
License:                BSD3
License-file:           LICENSE
Copyright:              Andy Gimblett <haskell@gimbo.org.uk>
Author:                 Andy Gimblett <haskell@gimbo.org.uk>
Maintainer:             Andy Gimblett <haskell@gimbo.org.uk>
Build-Type:             Custom
Cabal-Version:          >=1.6

Executable WxHello
  hs-source-dirs:       src
  Main-is:              Main.hs
  Build-Depends:        base >= 3 && < 5, cabal-macosx, wx
  ghc-options:          -fwarn-tabs -threaded -Wall
```

Here are the dylib files inside the generated package:

```
WxHello.app $ find . | grep dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/.cabal/lib/wxc-0.90.1.0/ghc-7.6.3/libwxc.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu_net-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_adv-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_aui-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_gl-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_html-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_propgrid-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_ribbon-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_richtext-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_stc-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_webview-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/Users/user/temp/wxWidgets-2.9.5/build-release/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-2.9.5.0.0.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
./Contents/Frameworks/usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
```

Answer (score 2):

The last redistributable I made in Windows with wxHaskell needed the files

- `mingwm10.dll` and
- `wxmws28u_gcc.dll`

to be in the *same folder as the .exe* (not just somewhere on my path).

This was using a previous version of wxHaskell, which compiled against a previous version of wxWidgits itself, so presumably you'd need the wx dll to have 29 in it rather than 28.

I compiled with static linking too:

```
ghc -static -optl-static -optl-mwindows Main -o Project.exe
```

the `-optl-mwindows` gets rid of the command prompt window which would otherwise appear alongside your app.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to include your .cabal and Setup.hs files.

From the documentation on cabal-macosx, it seems that you need to ensure that your MacApp data value in Setup.hs gets the appropriate mode for **ChaseDeps** (use **ChaseWithDefaults** instead of **DoNotChase**) in order to build redistributable app bundles.

If you have done that but still get the same error, I would check inside the resulting app bundle to see if the necessary libraries got copied in there at all. You may find enough information to file a bug with the cabal-macosx maintainer.

**Edit**

Based on what you've included, the setup looks correct, and it appears to have at least copied the library dependencies in. I think the problem is probably with the cabal-macosx package.

Looking at the source code to the dependency-fixup code, it looks like it should have printed a bunch of `"Updating <library>'s dependence on <path> to <path>"` lines as it was building the bundle. Did you see those? Were there any lines updating the binary itself?

I am not very experienced with the OS X linking process, but I would think that unless the binary is linked *after* copying the libraries, it would need to be updated as well.  You should be able to use `/usr/bin/otool -L <filename>` and `/usr/bin/install_name_tool` to manually fix up the paths in binaries the install process may have missed.

Here are the man pages for those two tools:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html